# How to get result for cities via google places api?

Tags: google-places-api

I am developing an application in which I am trying to get only cities names via google places api but the api is returning all the related results to related keyword.Below is the url I am using
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=jai&types=geocode&sensor=false&types=regions&key=AIzaSyAJP9EH1TnS5pYo-xEpQPEvBpbLXed8ets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you want to do, but remove the two `types=` parameters from your GET request and put `types=(cities)` instead.

See this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=jai&types=(cities)&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAJP9EH1TnS5pYo-xEpQPEvBpbLXed8ets